# getting aplay audio open error when using python pyttsx3 module in ubuntu docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, docker, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu docker container running in my ubuntu virtual machine which runs in my windows host. I have installed all necessary packages (apt update, apt upgrade, python3, pip3, pyttsx3, alsa-utils) in my ubuntu docker container. when I try to run the below code:

```
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("hello")
engine.runAndWait()
```

I am getting the following error

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5220:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
aplay: main:830: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Docker is designed as an isolation environment; programs in containers can't usually access the host's hardware devices without special permission.  The VM has simulated sound hardware, but the Docker container doesn't.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yep, I agree. Docker uses the same kernel whereas VM isolates the complete OS. But what can I do to overcome this issue, since docker is within the VM, it shares the same kernel.